# How to install Intel i40e v2.15.9 NIC driver on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: drivers, make

When I ran make install on Ubuntu 18.04.5 (kernel v4.15.0-187-generic) the following error occurred. Could you take a look at it to make it run successfully? Specifically, where should it be changed?

```
root@xxxxxxxxxxx:~/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src# make install                        
*** The target kernel has CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL enabled, but                        
*** the signing key cannot be found. Module signing has been                        
*** disabled for this build.                        
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-187-generic'                     
  CC [M]  /root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e_main.o                     
In file included from /root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e.h:33:0,                        
                 from /root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e_main.c:8:                      
/root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/kcompat.h:7248:28: error: redefinition of ‘skb_frag_off’                      
 static inline unsigned int skb_frag_off(const skb_frag_t *frag)                        
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~                        
In file included from ./include/linux/tcp.h:21:0,                       
                 from ./include/net/tcp.h:24,                       
                 from /root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e.h:7,                       
                 from /root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e_main.c:8:                      
./include/linux/skbuff.h:2763:28: note: previous definition of ‘skb_frag_off’ was here                      
 static inline unsigned int skb_frag_off(const skb_frag_t *frag)                        
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~                        
scripts/Makefile.build:333: recipe for target '/root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e_main.o' failed                        
make[2]: *** [/root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src/i40e_main.o] Error 1                        
Makefile:1590: recipe for target '_module_/root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src' failed                     
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/drivers/i40e-2.15.9/src] Error 2                        
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-187-generic'                      
Makefile:69: recipe for target 'default' failed                     
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: I'd guess the driver version is not compatible with the kernel version.  Older/newer versions of one of them might work better.   Check the driver, there may be a range of kernel versions it advertises it has been tested with.  Sometimes drivers like this either require or don't work with the HWE kernels. You also didn't mention where you got the driver from.  There may be a newer (working) version on Intel's website.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Actually when I installed on the same Ubuntu version, but "kernel 4.15.0-136-generic", it was successful.
so this difference of minor kernel version may be a cause of the failure? 
If there're compatibility documents referring to Ubuntu, Kernel, and Driver, it's so helpful.
*The driver I tried was from Intel website.
I tried the latest driver version (i40e v2.19.3) on the servers.
However, even though "modinfo i40e" showed the latest i40e-2.19.3, "ethtool -i {interface}" didn't reflect the same version (seems not updated).

Comment: Sounds like maybe an ubuntu patch to the official kernel may have broken something.

Comment: ok, what do you think is the next trial for the solution? Also, do you know anything about "error: redefinition of ‘skb_frag_off’"?